# How can I improve nested promise calls in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, promise

I am new to NodeJS.

I want to call kms.decrypt three times (nested) so that before the processEvents function is invoked, the variables populate their values.

Can you suggest how to write promise properly= How can I call them parallely so that they populate all their value before control goes to processEvents?

```
 exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {


kms.decrypt({ CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(pwd_e, 'base64') }).promise().then(function(data) {
    pwd_d = data.Plaintext.toString('ascii');
    kms.decrypt({ CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(acl_e, 'base64') }).promise().then(function(data) {
        acl_d = data.Plaintext.toString('ascii');
        kms.decrypt({ CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(usr_e, 'base64') }).promise().then(function(data) {
            usr_d = data.Plaintext.toString('ascii');
            processEvent(event, context, callback);
        });
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    context.done(err);
});
console.log(acl_d, usr_d, pwd_d);
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Here's what your code would look like if you used Promise.all:

```
Promise.all([
    kms.decrypt({ CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(pwd_e, 'base64') }).promise(),
    kms.decrypt({ CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(acl_e, 'base64') }).promise(),
    kms.decrypt({ CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(usr_e, 'base64') }).promise()
]).then(results => {
    const plainTexts = results.map(result => result.Plaintext.toString('ascii'));
    // plainTexts[0] === pwd_d in your code
    // plainTexts[1] === acl_d in your code
    // plainTexts[2] === usr_d in your code
    const [pwd_d, acl_d, usr_d] = plainTexts;
    processEvent(event, context, callback);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    context.done(err);
});
```